# Plugin/module communication method in multi-threaded C++ app

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am designing a C++ app which consists of largely independent plugins or modules which produce from time to time results useful for other plugins. For example, analysis module comes across some useful piece of data and sends it to action modules. Each module will run in its own thread; this is so analysis modules can continue gathering data while action modules handle the data at the rate they can.

I am looking for a suitable message passing architecture/design pattern. [This stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755670/architecture-for-extension-plugin-communication) gives some suggestions, but I'm not sure a plain interface will work in multi-threaded environment.

I was thinking of having some sort of channel based architecture, where each module broadcasts something on the channel and whichever module is interested in it - listens to. If there are some ready made libraries under liberal licence - the better.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using ACE (Adaptive Communication Environment) for thread management, TCP/UDP communications, mutex relationships and programming.

ACE is a highly portable collection of invocations of platform core patterns. Best of all, it's free, open source, and currently under active development.

http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html

For your application, I would recommend looking specifically at class "ACE_Task_Base" to provide multi-threading, and "ACE_Reactor" to register all the handlers for your asynchronous callback architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested to take a look at [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) library that acts like a concurrency framework also. Using this library your components would communicate with each other by sending messages to named ZeroMQ sockets. There are many sockets types (TCP, IPC, inproc) and several patterns available for request-reply and publish-subscribe messaging.